# Random crash on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: crash, reboot, plex

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on an Intel i5 based PC, mainly for media purposes, Plex server, ect. I find it unreachable every now and then, once every couple of days maybe.

I tried checking the disk for bad sectors, but it's all clean. I am way out of my depth here. Below is the screen that I find when it's non-reachable and I have to manually restart it:

[image]

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It sounds like it unmounted and remounted as read only.  First backup that drive.  It sounds like it might be in the early stages of disk failure, but it could also be something as simple as a loose/bad sata cable.

Answer (score 0):

I would start to diagnose to see if it's network > application/hardware.
When the server is in "unreachable" state are you able to ping/ssh the server?

If if it isn't a network issue then the next step would be testing the health of your application/services.
It would be easier to identify the fault while it is in a bad state before restarting it.

Comment: hi, I cant access the pc when its in that state, it would be just on black screen and throwing errors.

Comment: without details of your system it's hard to identify, but it's likely to be a hardware/storage issue.
do you see any errors from dmesg or syslog?